# Proof Check: $x \leq y+ \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ iff $x \leq y$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

**Synopsis**

I want to be sure I'm utilizing proof by contradiction correctly, so please check my proof of the exercise below. It's relatively simple, so it shouldn't take you too much time.

**Exercise**

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Show that $x \leq y + \epsilon$ for all real numbers $\epsilon > 0$ if and only if $x \leq y$.

**Proof**

Suppose $x \leq y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $x > y$. Then $x - y > 0$ and $x - y + \epsilon > \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. But if $x \leq y + \epsilon$, then $y - x + \epsilon \geq 0$. So $0 \leq y-x+\epsilon < y-x+(x-y+\epsilon) = \epsilon$, a contradiction. For the converse, suppose $ x \leq y$. Then it is obvious that $x \leq y+\epsilon$. This concludes our proof.

**Update**

This proof is obviously wrong. It is not a contradiction that $\epsilon >0$. For some reason, I deluded myself that my conclusion stated that $\epsilon < 0$, but that's just due to my occasional stupidity and habitual lack of double checking. Instead, consider some $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < x-y$. Then $x \leq y + \epsilon < y+x-y < x$, a contradiction. Thank you to the various people who commented on the issues with my proof. This was a very stupid mistake, and I don't even know how I overlooked what I did.

Comment: I think this post should be deleted by its author instead of being closed as a duplicate. It doesn't seem useful to future readers.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, I cannot delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0≤y−x+ϵ<y−x+(x−y+ϵ)=ϵ, a contradiction.

Why is that a contradiction?  $0$ **is** $< \epsilon$.

....

Instead Note $\epsilon$ is not fixed.  If $x-y >0$ then we can let $\epsilon$ be some value $0 < \epsilon < x-y$ and .... then what happens?

> $x \le y + \epsilon < y+(x-y) = x$ so $x < x$.  Which certainly *is* a contradiction!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't believe I made such a silly mistake ;-;

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. I tried to prove it by contradiction, and you got the conclusion that 0<\varepsilon, claiming that that's a contradiction. Why? There is no contradiction there.

If $x>y$, let $\varepsilon=\frac12(x-y)$. Then $\varepsilon>0$ and therefore $x\leqslant y+\varepsilon$. But this means that$$x\leqslant y+\frac12(x-y)=\frac12(x+y)<\frac12(x+x)=x.$$This gives you a contradiction: $x>x$.